# Javascript - How to check if cursor is on the last line?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, contenteditable

I am working on my javascript to check the cursor position in the contenteditable to see if the cursor is on the last line then return the boolean as true, otherwise false.

When I try this:

```
function checkLine() {

  var myElement = document.getElementById('editor');
   var startPosition = myElement.selectionStart;
   var endPosition = myElement.selectionEnd;
   var endofLine = false;

 if(startPosition == endPosition){
    endofLine = true;
 }
  return endofLine;
}
```

It is always return as true when I selected the cursor on the first line, second, third and forth lines in the contenteditable without the last line, it should have return as false when the cursor is not on the last line.

What I am trying to achieve is when I select on the first, second, third and forth lines in the contenteditable, I want the boolean to return as false and when I select the cursor on the last line, I want the boolean to return as true.

Can you please show me an example how I can check the cursor in the contenteditable that if they are on the end line then return the boolean as true otherwise false?

EDIT: Could you please clear up the code a bit and use something like this?

```
function checkLine() {
  // get last div
  const last = $('#editor').querySelector(":last-of-type");
  var endofLine = false;

  // if there is no div, that means there's only one line
  if (!last) {
     return true;
  }

  const sel = window.getSelection();
  let parent = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer;
  if (parent.nodeType !== 1) {
      parent = parent.parentNode;
  }
  return parent === last
}
```

Comment: You're comparing the start and end of the selection. This has nothing to do with the end of the input. You're setting it true when the selection is empty.

Comment: Last line as delimited by a new line or by wrapping?

Comment: @Barmar Yeah I understand that. I want to create the code for the current line of where the cursor is in right now and also create the total lines so I can comparing current line and total lines to see if the boolean will return as true or false??

Comment: @code I am not sure what you mean by the last line as delimited by a new line and by wrapping.

Comment: New line meaning the user presses "Enter" to create a new line, or line wrapping as in the line of text gets too long, so the rest of the text is moved onto the next line (the text is broken up between sentences).

Comment: Oh, yes it is new line when the user press enter. Can you be able to show me how I can detected in javascript that the user create new line on the bottom of the contenteditable to get the return boolean?

Comment: I edit my answer to work with `contenteditable Div`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can take advantage of the fact that with contenteditable divs, when a user enters a new line, a new div is automatically created for that line. This way, we can query the last div of the contenteditable and see if the cursor is in it.

```js
const editor = document.getElementById("editor")
editor.addEventListener("keyup", () => console.log(checkLine()))

function checkLine() {
  // get last div
  const last = editor.querySelector("div:last-of-type")
  
  // if there is no div, that means there's only one line
  if(!last) return true
  
  const sel = window.getSelection()
  let parent = sel.getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer
  if(parent.nodeType !== 1) parent = parent.parentNode
  return parent === last
}
```

```css
/* css just for the demo */
#editor { outline: none; }
#editor:empty::before {
  content: "Start typing...";
  pointer-events: none;
  color: #bbbbbb;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor" contenteditable></div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost exactly what i am looking for. So how I can use to call the checkline() function without the keyup??

Comment: And can you please clear up the code a bit to make it looks similar as the code I put in my question? Please see the question that I edited.

Comment: @chrisoojer sorry, not sure what you exactly mean about clearing up the code. The code should work fine regardless of the way you write it... You don't have to listen for the `keyup` event. You can call the function whenever.

Comment: Its code I have resolved it. Now i have a question, how I can use <br> as the last of type instead of div??

Comment: @chrisoojer this will require some major changes to the code.

Comment: Can you be able to do that for me please??

Answer (score -1):

When the user makes a line break in a `contenteditable` tag that string is wrapped in a `<div>`. In the example below when triggered by a "click" or "keydown" event on the `<fieldset contenteditable>` it will:

1. gather all `<div>` into an Array
2. find the specific `<div>` the user clicked on or typing into
3. display the line number
4. and display a message if it's the last line

```js
// Reference <form>
const main = document.forms.main;
/**
 * Reference all form controls in <form>
 * In this instance it's all <fieldset> and <output>
 */
const fc = main.elements;
// An array of multiple events
const events = ["click", "keydown"];
// Register fieldset#editor to the "click" and "keydown" nevents
events.forEach(e => fc.editor.addEventListener(e, lineBreak));

// Event handler passes Event Object by default
function lineBreak(e) {
  /**
   * Collect all direct descendant tags of #editor
   * and convert it into an Array. (all <div>)
   */
  const lines = Array.from(this.children);
  /**
   * Get the tag in which the cursor is in (the <div> 
   * clicked or typed into).
   */
  const L = window.getSelection().anchorNode.parentNode;
  // Find it's index and 1 to it
  let lineNo = lines.indexOf(L) + 1;
  // Set the value of output#line to that of lineNo OR 1
  fc.line.value = lineNo || 1;
  // If lineNo is equal to the total number of <div>s...
  if (lineNo === lines.length) {
    // ...add "last" class to output#line...
    fc.line.classList.add("last");
    // ...otherwise...
  } else {
    // ...remove "last" class to output#line
    fc.line.classList.remove("last");
  }
}
```

```css
.last {
  color: red;
}

.last::after {
  content: " is the last line";
}
```

```html
<form id="main">
  <fieldset id="ui">
    <legend>Line: <output id="line"></output></legend>
    <fieldset id="editor" contenteditable></fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>
```